# Equal height columns in rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use fitHeights (http://codepen.io/davatron5000/pen/fIqnF) to equalize rows of columns but I can't get it to calculate the height separately for each row. Does anyone have any ideas on how this can be modified to calculate each rows tallest container?

This is the example I'm working with. http://codepen.io/FernE97/pen/rzfid. Right now it is calculating the heights but it takes it from the tallest of the 4 instead of the tallest in each row.

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $.fn.fitHeights = function () {

        var items = $(this);

        function setHeights() {
            var currentTallest = 0;

            items.css({ 'min-height' : currentTallest }); // unset min-height to get actual new height

            items.each(function () {
                if ($(this).outerHeight() > currentTallest) { currentTallest = $(this).outerHeight(); }
            });

            items.css({ 'min-height' : currentTallest });
        }

        setHeights();
        $(window).on('resize', setHeights);
        return this;
    };

}(jQuery));

// on load
jQuery(window).load(function ($) {

    $('.fitheights .module').fitHeights();

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: I found a plugin called eqHeight.coffee that works well with mutliple rows. https://github.com/jsliang/eqHeight.coffee/

Answer (score 0):

hoping this helps but check out the updated codepen I did - essentially I created a sameHeights function and put a height on the image hopefully this will be of help to you
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fslvc

the js

```
  $.fn.sameHeights = function() {
    $(this).each(function(){
        var tallest = 0;
        $(this).children().each(function(i){
            if (tallest < $(this).height()) { tallest = $(this).height(); }
        });
        $(this).children().css({'height': tallest});
    });
    return this;
}; 

 $(window).load(function(){
/* $(groupOfItems).fitHeights(); */
 $('ul').sameHeights();
});
```

css

```
img { max-width: 100%; height:300px; }
```

Comment: Hi James, I was more looking for a fix for this one http://codepen.io/FernE97/pen/rzfid. The problem I'm having is that each column takes on the tallest one no matter if they are in their own row.